# How can I query a dictionary in a database table to filter for rows given a constant?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following database table, let's call it `features`:

```
 id      date       info 
 1   2024-02-15    {'ccy':'CHF', 'mic':'blvd', 'market_type': 56}   
 2   2024-02-15    {'ccy':'AUD', 'mic':'kkl', 'market_type': 33}
 ..
```

I would like to filter the rows where the `market_type` is not in a given list. Let's say the list is `[1,2,3,4,56]`

My query reads something like this:

```
select * from features where info ->> 'market_type' not in (1,2,3,4,56)
```

The above throws a syntax error. Any ideas what the right query is?

Comment: Try this  : 

SELECT *
FROM features
WHERE (info->>'market_type')::integer NOT IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 56);

Comment: Thanks you, that works! 
One more question please - is it possible instead of returning the whole rows, to return the 'market_type' instead?

Comment: `a syntax error`, would be nice to post the error message next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM features
WHERE CAST(info ->> 'market_type' AS INTEGER) NOT IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 56);
```

Here this CAST(info ->> 'market_type' AS INTEGER) is used to convert the value of market_type from a string to an integer.

Comment: One more question please - is it possible instead of returning the whole rows, to return the 'market_type' instead?

Comment: `SELECT CAST(info ->> 'market_type' AS INTEGER) AS market_type` 

You can print this way